# Fetch OpenStreetMap image for specified latitude–longitude

Tags: web-services, geospatial, openstreetmap

How can I **use an OpenStreetMap service** (an online server) to programmatically **fetch a street map image**, as a downloadable image file, **from just a latitude–longitude value** and zoom factor?

My application has a set of latitude–longitude values, and for each one I need an OpenStreetMap diagram – an image, not a web page – showing the location with a pin on the street map. The image needs to be a single SVG or PNG for further offline processing.

How can I programmatically construct a URL (at e.g. http://www.openstreetmap.org/ or http://www.opencyclemap.org/ or a similar service), parameterised by the latitude–longitude value and perhaps a zoom factor, that will return *just* the map image I'm interested in, including a pin at the location specified?

Comment: You can't.  You have to have the zoom level as well to be able to calculate which tile in the tile set to retrieve.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3238960/300257

Answer (score 6):

In order to fetch a particular tile, you have to provide the zoom, the x coordinate, and the y coordinate to the URL

Here's the URL for OpenStreetMap

```
http://[abc].tile.openstreetmap.org/zoom/x/y.png
```

The [abc] means that you use a or b or c.  These are three different subdomains on the OpenStreetMap server.

Here's a tile I pulled down using zoom 11, x = 510, y = 844

[image]

You have to convert latitude and longitude to an (x, y) coordinate.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3238960/300257) for a more complete explanation of tile sets and links to the conversion code.

You are limited in the number of tiles that you can retrieve from the OpenStreetMap servers.  Be sure to cache the tiles that you retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to access via WMS (web mapping service).  You can find a list of mirrors for OSM WMS [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers).  I'm not sure of your end use for it, but there are several links on this wiki page to projects that can consume WMS.  I've used [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) in some previous GIS projects and really liked it (don't know if this is your use-case though).